# Conway's Game of Life problem from python to C

Tags: python, c

I am trying to convert my code in python for game of life to C. But I am encountering some issues, also since I'd need to use it for multiple generation, I'd need to use an type int function and return board as a 2-d array. But I am not sure what is the best way of doing so. Below is the code in python and C. Also, I'm stuck with the nested loop, but could not figure out why I am getting the seg faults.

```
void game_of_life(int board[5][5]) {
    int m = 5;
    int n = 5;
    int moves[8][2] = {{-1, 1},
                       {-1, 0},
                       {-1, -1},
                       {0,  -1},
                       {0,  1},
                       {1,  0},
                       {1,  -1},
                       {1,  1}};
    int dm = 8;
    int grid[m][n];
    memcpy(board, grid, sizeof(grid));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < dm; k++) {
                int cr = i + moves[k][0];
                int cc = j + moves[k][1];

                if (cr >= 0 && cr < m && cc >= 0 && cc < n) {
                    total += board[cr][cc];
                    printf("%d", total);
                }
            }
            if (total < 2 || total > 3) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            } else if (total == 3) {
                board[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                board[i][j] = grid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int k =0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        for(int l=0; l<5; l++)
        {
            printf("%d", board[k][l]);


        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

```
    m = len(board)
    n = len(board[0])
    moves = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)] # eight possible neighbors
    grid = [row[:] for row in board] # make a copy of the grid
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n): # for each cell, check how many neighbors alive
            total = 0 
            
            for di, dj in moves: # check every neighbor
                
                cr = i + di # finding the xy-index of neighbor 
                cc = j + dj
                
                if 0 <= cr < m and 0 <= cc < n: # check if it falls in valid range
                    total += grid[cr][cc] # increment the total neighbor alive for current cell
                
            
            if total < 2 or total > 3: # if the total is less than 2 or greater than three, set the value to 0
                board[i][j] = 0
                
            elif total == 3: # if the total is 3, set the value to 1
                board[i][j] = 1
                print(i,j, board[i][j])
            
            else: # else, the value remains unchanged, copy it from the original grid
                board[i][j] = grid[i][j]
    
    
    return board
```

Comment: Don't "convert" existing code. Reimplement the algorithm instead.

Comment: As for your problem, learn [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, use a *debugger* to catch the crash, to locate when and where in your code it happens, and examine the values of all involved variables at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 4):

Using gdb, I was able to figure out that It would crash at

```
            if (total < 2 || total > 3) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            } else if (total == 3) {
```

because `i` was 548

Look at your loops.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < dm; k++) {
                int cr = i + moves[k][0];
                int cc = j + moves[k][1];
```

in the second one, you do `i++` again. Change it to `j++`

If you're going to copy+paste your nested loops, make sure you pay attention to details like this so you don't end up with confusing and simple errors.